# Как склоняется и какого рода слово "нод(а)"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, жаргон, род, неологизмы

Нода - это заимствование от слова node (узел). Из [викисловаря](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), узнал, что это слово женского рода (вроде как). Используется в компьютерных приложениях для обозначения блока программы, который соединяется с другими нодами и образует сложную структуру:

[image]

Также используется для обозначения компьютера в специфических сетях

Кое-что очевидно и используется повсеместно:

> Нодовый редактор
>
> Ноды
>
> Группа нодов

Кое-что неочевидно, и примеров использования не найти. Например, каким образом склонять это слово, особенно во фразах:

> Использовать активную нод(у)
>
> Выделенных нод(ов)
>
> Цвет ноды(?)
>
> Добавить к ноде(у)

Точно ли это слово женского рода?

Есть варианты использования как мужского рода:

> Исправляем это недоразумение используя нод Hue/Saturation/Value.

https://pikabu.ru/story/vozmozhnosti_sovremennoy_kompyuternoy_grafiki_4291152

так и женского:

> Нода Copy. Наследование трансформаций и атрибутов. Техника Copy
> Stamping.

http://vfxlaboratory.ru/kurs/houdini-artist-101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В сфере IT работаю уже почти 30 лет. По рабочим вопросам общаюсь с огромным количеством коллег и всегда слово **"нода"** было женского рода. Иногда доводилось слышать применение этого слова в мужском роде от начинающих IT-шников, но обычно старшие товарищи рано или поздно объясняли им, как должно быть правильно, и они исправлялись ;)

И кстати, это не единственный парадокс, доставшийся нам со времен [ФИДО](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82). Два наиболее значимых термина там имеют совершенно нелогичный род. Кроме **ноды**, которая в оригинале **"node"** (**узел**), и поэтому, по идее, должна была бы быть мужского рода, есть еще **поинт**, который имеет мужской род, хотя в оригинале он **point** ("**точка**"), и должен был бы иметь женский род.

Что же касается примеров неправильного применения рода этих слов на некоторых ресурсах - то тут, по-видимому, виновато слишком быстрое расширение круга энтузиастов, которые не сразу успевают ознакомиться с традиционной терминологией. Но они тоже исправятся, поверьте :)

Comment: В жаргоне геймеров я встречал это слово лишь в мужском роде: нод. Интересно, может быть, это как-то связано с тем, что начинающие айтишники были геймерами со стажем? :)

Comment: @Aer, вполне может быть. Я, к моему большому сожалению, никак не могу найти время, достаточное для того, чтобы влиться в стан геймеров :( Впервые слово "нода" я услышал в конце восьмидесятых - начале девяностых. Тогда оно использовалось в основном в телекоммуникациях. Позднее, это слово начало активно использоваться программистами, т.к. появились языки разметки с этим термином. У геймеров, насколько я понимаю, ноды начали использоваться сравнительно недавно, возможно независимо от связистов и программистов. Возможно из-за этого у них сложилась несколько иные традиции использования этого слова.

Comment: Ну, может, и не обязательно вливаться в их стан — в конце концов, не будучи ребенком или профессиональным геймером, трудно и едва ли стоит посвящать играм много времени. Другое дело — потратить пару часов в неделю, чтобы развлечься :) Конечно, ваши свидетельства указывают на то, что изначально была именно _нода_. Я думаю, что геймерское _нод_ появилось независимо и приобрело грамматический род в соответствии с английским произношением (/nəʊd/ --> нод, как кот, рот, пот и т. д.).

Comment: @Aer, я просто по-доброму завидую тем, кому удается совмещать работу и игры. Очень хочется когда-нибудь стать одним из этих счастливых людей. Но боюсь, что это уже будет только ближе к пенсии...

Comment: Ох, понимаю вас... Давайте надеяться, что это станет осуществимым в ближайшее время, — а там, глядишь, и правда получится :)